# Increase an integer every specified seconds c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

You will see under the void start function the currentWave. I want it to increment by 1 every 20 seconds. but not sure where and how to go about doing so. Below you will see my declared variables. I have left out the other section of code as it is not necessary for what I need.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int currentWave;
    private float startTime;
    private float currentTime;
```

Above is my declared variables, and below is my stary function with currentWave set to 1, which is the integer I want to change every 20 seconds.

```
    void Start()
    {
        currentWave = 0;
        startTime = Time.time;
        StartCoroutine(SpawnEnemy(TimeFrame[currentWave]));
    }

    void Update()
    {
        currentTime = Time.time - startTime;
        Debug.Log(currentTime);
    }
}
```

I used my update function to get the current "running time" of the program.

Comment: You can use `Time.DeltaTime` to measure time. Otherwise, `FixedUpdate` runs every frame, at a fixed time then.

Answer (score 1):

Use a coroutine:

```
private IEnumerator waveIncrementer;

void Start()
{
    currentWave = 0;
    startTime = Time.time;
    StartCoroutine(SpawnEnemy(TimeFrame[currentWave]));
    waveIncrementer = IncrementWave();
    StartCoroutine(waveIncrementer);
}

IEnumerator IncrementWave() 
{
    WaitForSeconds waiter = new WaitForSeconds(20f);
    while (true)
    {
        yield return waiter;
        currentWave++;
    }
}
```

if you want it to increment immediately, put `currentWave++` before `yield return waiter;`:

```
IEnumerator IncrementWave() 
{
    WaitForSeconds waiter = new WaitForSeconds(20f);
    while (true)
    {
        currentWave++;
        yield return waiter;
    }
}
```

Then, you can stop it with `StopCoroutine(waveIncrementer);`

Comment: I get an error - Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.WaitForSeconds' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerator' Assembly-CShar- on the line - IEnumerator waiter = new WaitForSeconds(20f);

Comment: @KyleWestran oh yeah, silly me. Try `WaitForSeconds waiter = new WaitForSeconds(20f);`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [**InvokeRepeating**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html)

Comment: no, my game object is in an array, and current wave is the value i use to switch to the next array

Comment: It's kind of hard understanding what you want to do without the rest of your code. But from what I could gather, you have a coroutine that spawn the enemies which depend on a index. That index is the one you need to increase every 20 seconds. You can easily pass the int by ref (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) on a invoke repeating coroutine and the int will be updated every 20 seconds. I don't think this is the cleanest way of doing it, but without the rest of your code this is the best I could think.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to update it every frame. Just compute it when you need it. Change the field to a property, and return a computed value.

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float startTime;
    private float CurrentTime
    {
        get
        {
            return Time.time - startTime;
        }
    }
```